# How to resolve "error : rzc discover exited with code 150"

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

My dotnet SDK version is 3.0.100. I am trying to run an angular web application which is wrap with dotnet core framework in macOS. But whenever I try to build the project, It gives me the following error.

```
/Users/juthisarker/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.2.0/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(80,5): error : rzc discover exited with code 150. [/Users/juthisarker/Documents/webTest/testtwo/testtwo.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

At first, my dotnet SDK version was 3.1.1. Then, I downgrade my dotnet SDK version to 3.0.100. I thought it will solve the framework's razor design issue. But, It didn't resolve the issue. I have given testtwo.csproj file here also.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
    <RootNamespace>truck_tracking</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
     <!-- <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="2.2.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core" Version="2.2.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="2.2.0" /> -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: can you show us your `/Users/juthisarker/Documents/webTest/testtwo/testtwo.csproj` file?

Comment: @vasily.sib, Yes! I have edited my post and give the  testtwo.csproj file.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this `.csproj` file looks like for `netcoreapp2.2`, not 3.1 nor 3.0 ?

Comment: I have this same project which is running well in windows. In that windows OS, the dotnet core framework SDK version is 3.0.0 and its the same testtwo.csproj file. I don't really understand where the problem is.

Comment: I've been having the same problem. Did anybody find a solution for this?

Comment: Me too on GitHub pipeline

Comment: @LetieTechera, I downloaded .dotnet core version 2.2 as project requirement that resolve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is because some project references package(s) requiring .Net Core 2.x version.

On CentOS 7 I have installed 2.1 in parallel to 3.1 and now all works:

```
yum install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

Alternatively (and maybe preferably) you can set environment variable:

```
export DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD_ON_NO_CANDIDATE_FX=2
```

Comment: That's helped a lot! Thank you.